# CMake building targets conditionally based on library existence

Tags: build, cmake

I have a large cross-platform project which needs to build in various places; in some places, different UI toolkits, sound APIs, etc. may be available, and I am trying to figure out the best way to automatically configure which targets get configured based on which libraries are present.

The code I am trying for that is, for example:

```
find_library(PC_EGL EGL)
find_library(PC_GLESv2 GLESv2)
find_library(PC_Xxf86vm Xxf86vm)
if (DEFINED PC_EGL AND DEFINED PC_GLESv2 AND DEFINED PC_Xxf86vm)
  add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(foo ${PC_EGL} ${PC_GLESv2} ${PC_Xxf86vm})
endif()
```

However, in the case that I build this on a system which doesn't have libGLESv2 available, I get the error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PC_GLESv2
    linked by target "foo" in directory /path/to/platform
```

The find_library documentation implies that the variable PC_EGL_NOTFOUND should be getting set, but it isn't (CMake 2.8.5).  So, what is the appropriate way to use find_library to determine whether a target should be made to exist at all?  It seems like using

```
if (NOT PC_EGL MATCH "-NOTFOUND")
```

is a bit fragile and fiddly, so is there a better mechanism for determining a CMake command path based on wheter a library was found at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simply

```
if(PC_EGL AND PC_GLESv2 AND PC_GLESv2)
```

CMake treats `0`, `FALSE`, `OFF`, `ANYTHING-NOTFOUND` as false.

Comment: Thanks! That seems like it should have been easy to find in the documentation or examples, which is a common problem I have with CMake - once I know how to do something it's easy, but finding how to do it, not so much.